# Electrical shock, why should I get it?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

So I got electrical shock from an electric hot water heater about an hour ago, I've no idea the measure of the electricity released but It leaved pain, shaking on my right arm and somehow around my stomach up to now, so I've been taking a rest on my bed right now. But I'm just wondering.

I didn't stand on ground but ceramics floor at 2nd floor, as per my understanding that , indeed, our bodies are good or might have been perfect conductors, but doesn't the flow of electricity need completeness of circuit, which turns out to be, in my case the earth?

Comment: Was the ground dry or wet?

Comment: The floor? a bit humid though, I've just realized it.

Comment: Your question looks unclear, make it more clear. What exactly are you asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your comment, as the floor was not completely dry, the humidity has acted as a conductor to some extent, and that is why you have got a shock. We all know that tap water conducts electricity.

Now, for the sake of argument, if I consider that the floor was dry, then it can be said that sometimes, so-called insulators may conduct electricity. Marble flooring of bathrooms also conduct sometimes. It is mainly due to the fact that ceramic tiles may have had some impurity that conducted electricity, due to which you have got a shock.

Answer (score 3):

> Doesn't the flow of electricity need completeness of circuit?

The flow of *alternating current* does not require *continuity* of a circuit.  Even if your body is completely insulated from everything else, a small amount of electrical charge can flow through your finger and accumulate on your body when you touch a live wire.  Then when the polarity of the wire reverses, the charge will flow in the opposite direction.  It will continue to flow back and forth until you break contact.

The amount of charge that can flow in that way is very small, but it's enough for you to be able to feel it (Don't ask me how I know!)

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance